# Past continuous vs Past simple

Tags: verbs, past-tense

*Sebastian (arrive) ... at Susan's house a little before 9:00 PM, but she (be, not) ... there. She (study, at the library) ... for her final examination in French.*

Could you explain, please, what and **why** verb tenses should be used in the above sentences?
If it possible tell me please what 'use' from the following site determines verb tense:

- http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html
- http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html

Answer (score 0):

The first one is simple past, use one:

> Sebastian **arrived** at Susan's house a little before 9:00 PM...

The second one is past continuous, use two:

> ...but she **was not** there *(at that time)*.

The third one is past continuous, use one:

> She **was studying at the library** for her final examination in French *(at that time)*.

Comment: 1. We use 'Present Simple' because this is a completed action? 2. We use 'Past Continuous' because there is interrupted action by  arriving 3. We use 'Past Continuous' because there is interrupted action by  arriving ?